# Refactoring to remove try/catch

Tags: c#, exception, refactoring

Any ideas on a good way to refactor this so that my code acts the same, but without the whole throwing and catching my own exception?

```
public Int32 ChooseNextColor(Int32 numColors)
{
    int? nextColor = null;

    while (nextColor == null)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your next color selection: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            nextColor = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            if (nextColor > numColors || nextColor < 0) 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        catch
        {
            nextColor = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized input: " + input);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and " + numColors + ".");
        }
    }

    return (nextColor.Value);
}
```

**EDIT**: The try/parse method is exactly what I am looking for.

In response to John's title edit -> I should have posted more information to begin with, and that would have been "getting rid of the try/catch all together is best".  So with that in mind, I changed the title.

Comment: John, I'm not sure that's a good edit of the title.  The question asks about "without ... throwing and catching my own exception" which to me suggests he's asking about how to handle the range validation (his ArgumentOutOfRangeException) rather than the integer parsing.

Comment: The answers are all about `int.TryParse`, so I'll have to disagree until the OP clarifies.

Comment: See **but without the whole throwing and catching my own exception**. That most answers don't answer the initial question shouldn't be a reason to change the question

Comment: Saw that, saw the answers, waiting on the OP to tell us so we can stop guessing.

Comment: Most of the questions did not answer my original question, but I also did not put enough information in the question to begin with.  Removing the try/catch is indeed the best response I was looking for.  Voting up for pointing out my lack of information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
int nextColor;
input = Console.ReadLine();

while( ! Int32.TryParse( input, out nextColor ) 
       || nextColor > numColors 
       || nextColor < 0 )
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized input: " + input);
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and " + numColors + ".");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to perform the range validation of the original code... am I missing something?

Comment: this doesn't check if the input is between 0 and numColors.

Comment: Doesn't get rid of the throwing out of range when its < 0?

Comment: Right...added the range validation.

Comment: I would hope the original user could figure out how to add range validation to @Paul's existing code.

Comment: The question was about how to get rid of the try/catch used for range validation, not about exceptions from `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: I really dont like the idea of having 2 readline statements in the same function, but this is the best answer.  +1 for the succinct code, I'll be using something slightly refactored from this.

Answer (score 4):

warning, not tested!

```
public int ChooseNextColor(int numColors)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your next color selection: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int color;
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out color) || color > numColors || color < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized input: " + input);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and " + numColors + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET provides `TryParse` for just this reason.

Comment: Doesn't get rid of the throwing out of range when its < 0?

Comment: He is trying to get around throwing his own exception and catching it, not just the exception thrown by Convert.ToInt32

Comment: Once the exception thrown by `Parse` is gone, it's an elementary change to remove the try/catch entirely. Consider it left as an exercise to the reader, if you must.

Comment: But that was the whole point of his question.  He didn't say anything about the exception from Convert.ToInt32

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Int32.TryParse()` or

```
if (nextColor > numColors || nextColor < 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized input: " + input);
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and " + numColors + ".");
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid exception, you should use int.TryParse method instead of Convert.ToInt32().

Comment: Doesn't get rid of the throwing out of range when its < 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Int32 ChooseNextColor(Int32 numColors)
    {
        var success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your next color selection: ");
            int nextColor;
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            success = int.TryParse(input, out nextColor);

            if (success && nextColor > 0 && nextColor < numColors) return nextColor;

            Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized input: " + input);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and " + numColors + ".");
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("The thing that should not be.");
    }
```